# Detect currently selected source of custom elements

Tags: plugin-development, elementtype

I have a split-style `+ New Element` button for my custom element type. Thanks to [this previous thread](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/10838/45), the right-side dropdown menu is working perfectly!

[image: Split button]

My question now is, **how do I get the `+ New Element` side of it working?**

I keep studying the `entries` templates, to see how it's done over there. But I've noticed that when you navigate between entry sources, *the page URL actually changes*. When navigating between my custom element sources, the page URL does not change.

**How can I help the `+ New Element` button detect what source is currently being viewed?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see how this is working by opening craft/app/resources/js/craft.js and searching for the `Craft.EntryIndex` class definition.

Craft.EntryIndex is an extension of Craft.BaseElementIndex, and is used to govern *all* Entry indexes in Craft (including Entry selection modals). We pull that off with this line of code, which you’ll find immediately after the class definition:

```js
Craft.registerElementIndexClass('Entry', Craft.EntryIndex);
```

The logic governing the “New Entry” button is a little complicated, and it relies on an initial version of the button HTML already being available on the page (thanks to the craft/app/templates/entries/_edit.html template), but all the magic happens within its onSelectSource() method, including updating the URL.

Comment: Very interesting... I started to go down that path, but wanted to make sure I was headed in the right direction. I'll take another crack at it with this information in mind. Thanks Brandon! :)